# How to keep track of nonces with HD Wallet Provider (or any other tools)?

Tags: hd-wallets

I'm trying to send trades with a list of let's say 5 different addresses created with HDWallet Provider using a seed phrase (or mnemonic). I do want to know what is the current nonce of each of the addresses, is there an easy way to do this provided by HD-WP? Unfortunately I couldn't find much information about it.

They mention in their Github docs something about a shareNonce parameter when creating the provider object, could someone explain what exactly is this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your nonce start at 0 and you can increment it every transactions. Also you can retrieve your nonce with web3.Js.